# selected from nested select using join

Tags: sql

User send me arbitrary SQL (I know a bit about it, i know it has ID column) and I need to be able to filter down to records that have entries in a different table.

ie i want to do something like this

```
select * from (<user sql>) join t1 on t1.MemberID = ID where t1.Key = '12345'
```

This works but my result set ends up containing all columns of t1 as well as the user ones. I only want the columns of the user supplied query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using table aliases and `exists` -- and only selecting the columns you want:

```
select t.*
from (<user sql>) t
where exists (select 1 
              from t1 
              where t1.MemberID = t.ID and t1.Key = '12345'
             );
```

Why `exists`?  This prevents duplication if `t1` happens to  have any duplicates.